# Why does this give me an error saying NoSuchElementException when the link text is present in the html?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to log in into my instagram account but when I try to click the login button I get the error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I'm trying to find this element

```
 <div class="Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_    _4EzTm">Log In</div>
```

Shouldn't I be able to use

```
login = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log In')
```

or

```
login = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Log In')))
```

to access that element?

Why don't either of them work?

Comment: A link is an <a> tag, in what you've shared your element is a <div> - which is why you cannot find by link text. You can try by.xpath with  //div[text()='Log In']

Comment: @RichEdwards So I tried driver.find_element_by_xpath('// div[text() = Log In]') but it said that it wasn't a valid xpath, can you help me on this?

Comment: You've copied it wrong. You've moved the quotes around. Try driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Log In']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw, the class attribute had the value                     `Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm`

So the line of code in your program won't work because the attribute value is wrong and it changes frequently. I would avoid these alphanumeric values as a reference in any website as majority of them are dynamically generated.

I suggest you to use `xpath` to find these buttons mostly or `id` if you could find any. Most of them are not dynamic and also lucky for us they are unique too.  This one will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()
```

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again but if you wouldn't mind can you tell me why this xpath doesn't work? //*[@id = "ytp-id-17"]/div/div[2]/div[2] when I'm trying to path to the next button on youtube?

Comment: That's because the `Next` icon disappears 2 seconds after the video starts to play. You need to hover the mouse near it to make it visible so that `Selenium` can interact with it. On the contrary, you can use keyboard shortcut to go the next video like this :  `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,'n')`. This open the next video on the same tab anytime you want to. You have to import `Keys` before doing this using this line `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, really appreciate it, but the thing is I tried to do the same thing to open a new tab driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'T')
I did this but nothing happened, I didn't even get an error, what went wrong? also I am using a PC so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Not every key shortcut works, some have been decommissioned recently. You can use JS to open a new tab and then switch to the tab through selenium. `driver.execute_script('window.open("");')` and then switch to the next tab using `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`. The `driver.window_handles` gives an array which has the opened tab id's present in it. You can switch to any tab using the `driver.switch_to.window()`. Mostly for best practices we stick to a single tab, although it is not prohibited you can use it.